# ¿Cómo evitar que se desmarquen mis checkbox al refrescar la pagina?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una consulta :

Como puedo evitar que se desmarquen lo checkbox seleccionados al refrescar la página de mi html.

```
<body>
    <label for="">Proyecto</label>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="idchkProyecto">
</body>
```

Comment: Podrías guardar sus valores en un `localStorage` para volver a asignarlos cuando la pagina se recargue, depende de cuanto tiempo quieres que persista la información.

Comment: te agradeceria un ejemplo ya que soy nuevo en programación.

Comment: Tal vez podrías proporcionar mas contexto para poder dar una respuesta mas indicada al problema.

Comment: puedes usar el **localstorage** de cada navegador y al recargar leer los datos guardados que tengas y despues cargar los datos

Answer (score 3):

Como bien te han comentado, puedes utilizar `localStorage` para almacenar el valor de la propierad *checked* de tu checkbox.

Puedes crear un *script* que guarde este valor en respuesta al **evento *change***, y que siempre que se recargue la página recupere el valor de *localStorage*.

Aunque puede hacerse de muchas maneras, aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>
    <label for="">Proyecto</label>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="idchkProyecto">
</body>

<script>

checkbox = document.getElementById('idchkProyecto')
checkbox.checked = eval(window.localStorage.getItem(checkbox.id))

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
    window.localStorage.setItem(checkbox.id, checkbox.checked)
})

</script>

</html>
```

`localStorage` almacena datos en forma de **pares clave-valor**. En el ejemplo he utilizado como clave el atributo *id* del *checkbox*, y como valor el de su propiedad *checked*.

Con el método *setItem* guardas los datos, y los recuperas con *getItem*.

Ten en cuenta que todo lo que se guarda en `localStorage` es texto (Strings), por eso en el ejemplo he utilizado la función `eval()` para evaluar `"true"` o `"false"` y obtener así `true` o `false`, que son los valores *booleanos* que determinan si el *checkbox* está o no activado.

Otra alternativa es `sessionStorage` (los datos permanecerán guardados al recargar la página pero se perderán al cerrar el navegador).

Answer (score 1):

Usando JQuery puedes hacer esto (importante que tus checkboxs tengan un id):

```
// Obtienes los valores
var values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxes')) || {};
var $checkboxes = $(":checkbox"); // Tomas los checkboxs

// Al cambiar el valor
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
  $checkboxes.each(function(){
    values[this.id] = this.checked;
  });
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxes", JSON.stringify(values));
});

// Al cargar
$.each(values, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
});
```