# Marcar una casilla de verificación por defecto inicialmente

Tags: javascript

Tengo un formulario con un campo que es un campo de verificación (*checkbox*), llamado `cFMed`.

Me gustaría que, inicialmente, aparezca marcado por defecto y que al desmarcar e la casilla y guardar el formulario aparezca luego el valor almacenado correctamente, es decir, desmarcado.

[image: Imagen de check]

Le incluí el atributo `checked` en la etiqueta de la casilla y eso me lo marcaba por defecto inicialmente, pero al desmarcarlo y luego guardar no me hacía nada y me lo volvía a mostrar una vez que abría el formulario de nuevo.

Además, hay campos del formulario que he modificado y al pulsar el botón guardar sí lo ha guardado correctamente, es decir, que no es por el botón guardar.

Tras esto, me he pasado a quitar el `checked` de la etiqueta del HTML y hacerlo todo en javascript, pero no consigo hacer que aparezca e la casilla marcada por defecto y luego al desmarcarla y guardar aparezca desmarcada.

Adjunto mi código actual:

```
function checkFMed(casilla,mapaDependencias) {  
var cformMed = document.getElementById('cFMed');
var cValor = '';

    if (!cformMed.checked == true) {
        cValor= cformMed .value;
    }

}
```

Me gustaría que la solución fuese a través de javascript (no incluir el `checked`).

Comment: ¿Podrías explicarnos mejor "pero al desmarcarlo y luego guardar no me hacia nada y me lo volvía a mostrar una vez que abría el formulario de nuevo"? Estás diciendo que el estado de esa casilla la guardas en una base de datos y luego quieres que se mantenga según lo almacenado en la base de datos? Eso se hace en el lado del servidor, por lo que tendrás que darnos más información acerca del lenguaje que usas del lado del servidor.

Comment: voy a mirar, pero como podría precargarlo a marcado cuando se accede al formulario? y que no sea con la etiqueta "checked"

Comment: Primero necesito saber cómo rellenas el resto de formularios y cómo has intentado hacerlo con esa casilla. Cuando compartas ese código podré decirte la manera correcta de hacerlo porque conoceré el lenguaje que estás usando en el servidor y sabré aplicarlo al HTML que debe generarse.

Comment: Cuando puedas compartir el código que te solicitamos [edita tu pregunta pulsando aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/386730/edit) para agregar el código. Es importante esa parte para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Si tu intención es hacerlo todo *del lado del cliente* utiliza `localStorage`: [¿Cómo evitar que se desmarquen mis checkbox al refrescar la pagina?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/301450/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-que-se-desmarquen-mis-checkbox-al-refrescar-la-pagina/301455#301455)